# ctrl-c, ctrl-v not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, clipboard

I'm trying to use my Windows 7 PC, and for some reason, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste only work intermittently.

I have a third-party clipboard viewer installed, so I can see when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't copy to the clipboard (there's no new entry) and also when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> pastes glarp (the cursor moves, sometimes several lines) instead of what's on the clipboard.

I've checked the keyboard and mouse drivers, run a system scan, checked the event log and a bunch of other things I've seen online, and haven't found a resolution.

Any other ideas for things to check or try?

Comment: Programs have to support Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V. So it could be windows, or the program you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check carefully any programs with clipboard-related functionality. I use a program called TinyGrab that takes screenshots and then puts a URL to them in the clipboard, and in older versions sometimes it would crash out and the clipboard would stop working entirely. I'm not sure how this happens, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

Try crtl+shift+c first . Then ctrl+c will work.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that in Notepad and it worked. You saved my time! Could you please explain what the cause is?

Answer (score 0):

You say that Ctrl+V makes the cursor move, but doesn't paste what's on the clipboard.
If you doubt what's on the clipboard, open up windows notepad and press Ctrl+V.  If the clipboard contains text, you'll see it. If it just seems to make the cursor move, the the clipboard has some spaces, tabs, and/or linebreaks.  Believe it.
It seems likely that something is interfering with the clipboard, quite possibly your clipboard utility.  Does this behavior continue when it isn't running?  Not all clipboard utilities are good about not interfering.  I know, because I wrote one, and I sent to a lot of trouble to make sure that I stayed out of the way of the primary copy/paste activity.

Answer (score 0):

For me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not work simultaneously with ScreenGrab Pro in Win7. I checked several times, and this was the reason.

If that is not your issue, go to Control Panel, uninstall keyboard driver and restart the computer.

Comment: Am I missing something here? The OP never mentioned ScreenGrab Pro... or any screen capture software, for that matter. She also indicated that her keyboard driver is okay. This doesn't really seem like an answer for this question, although the tiny chance that you could be right makes me hesitant to downvote.